# Background image does repeats on righthandside with bootstrap on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to bootstrap and have tested my webpage on a few browsers.

When I make the width of the tab smaller on chrome, either from the left or right in chrome, part of the image is cropped and put on the other side of the image. The imgur picture shows the problem.

Any help or advice is appreciated!

[This is the issue of bootstrap with chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0d6R.png)

[My website page with a problem is here](http://www.theoriginalbeng.com/html/welcome.html)

I've put my css code below:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    /*height: 50%;*/
    background-image: url("/galleryPhotos/whiteVan2.jpeg");
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    top: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these to your css, it seems to work for me in your example.

```
-webkit-background-size: cover; //safari chrome
-moz-background-size: cover; // firefox
-o-background-size: cover; // opera
```

Here is a fiddle for it (different pic though): https://jsfiddle.net/46zcm0yL/

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help (mark it answered to help others and thank me! :))